# Which Maven Parent POM has the Version of a specific Artifact

Tags: java, maven

In my project we are using hierarchy dependency. For example(*in reality there are multiple layers*): 
`GrandParent_pom.xml` 
`-->Parent_pom.xml` 
`---->Child_pom.xml` 

For few artifacts, version number is defined in parent pom, for few others version number is defined in GrandParent pom. 
Is there any way we can generate a report(like dependency:tree goal) which will say in which pom we have defined the version of each artifact.

Comment: you can use the tool exists in eclipse. When you open your pom.xml click in dependency hierarchy. I thinks this can help you.

Comment: Yes, But in my case multiple artifacts are there(around 100 dependencies) and the there are around 7 intermediate POMs between the child and root pom. I am checking whether any goal/ libraries exist that ease my work

Comment: I would advice you to reduce the number of layers manage the versions coherently. Your question implies that the project is in a bad state.

Comment: When we hover over the artifact in eclipse, eclipse will suggest which pom has the version number, if anyone knows how it is getting derived that would be helpful